# unrecognized selector sent to class when create a singleton object

Tags: ios, singleton

I have a shared class

`.h`

`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ArraysClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,copy)NSMutableArray *mutArraySongs;


+(ArraysClass *)SharedManager;

@end
```

`

`.m`

`

```
#import "ArraysClass.h"

@implementation ArraysClass

static ArraysClass *sharedService = nil;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+(ArraysClass *)sharedManager {
    if(sharedService == nil){
    sharedService = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
}
return sharedService;
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;
 }

-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    // initialize stuff here
   // user=[LoggedUser sharedManager];
}

return self;
```

}

@end

`

In my `ViewController` I need to create an object from this. I did like this

`

```
 #import "ArraysClass.h"
 ArraysClass *arrayClass=[ArraysClass SharedManager];
```

`

But this last line giving me an exception like this

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ArraysClass SharedManager]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x13e9c8'`

why is that? and how can I solve this problem? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Declared method as

```
+(ArraysClass *)SharedManager;
```

You implemented

```
+(ArraysClass *)sharedManager
```

and you are invoking

```
[ArraysClass SharedManager]
```

In implementation use `SharedManager` instead of sharedManager.. i.e. **s** should be capital.

Here the case is your method is not implemented because its name is different.

Answer (score 0):

error tells that Compiler Failed to find your selector, change sharedManger method as u declared in your interface, now case sensitivity is the cause..